# How do I create a child entity in Golang AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm attempting to create a Child entity based on the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities

When I intiate the user instance, I'm getting an error "issing ',' in argument list" even though there is only one agument.

When I attempt to assign the parent value to Prospect on initiation, I get this error:
    expected '==', found '='

```
func sign(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)  
    zip, err := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("zip"))  

    //user := user.Current(c)  
    user = Client(name: "Bryan")   
    // error thrown "missing ',' in argument list"

    p = Prospect(parent=user )
    // error thrown: expected '==', found '='  
    p := Prospect{  
        Name:  r.FormValue("name"),  
        Zip:  zip,  
        Date:  time.Now(),  
    }
```

It looks just like the examples in the documentation, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Follow the Go docs, not the Python docs...  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/entities

Comment: I did not notice I had been redirected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the App Engine docs and writing in Go, you constantly get redirected to the Python docs. It is the most annoying thing on the planet. Always check the URL you are at after navigation and clicking links. If you are in the right place, you should find "go" in the URL somewhere. If it shows python or java, replace it with go in the URL and hope it exists.

So the page you really want is this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/entities